# How to make 'symfony doctrine:build-sql' task generate 'DROP' statments?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Is there a way to make **symfony doctrine:build-sql** task generate **DROP** statments before **CREATE TABLE** ones as it **symfony *propel*:build-sql** does ?
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such possibility, but you can run the doctrine:drop-db task before inserting the the SQL. A regular way with doctrine is:

```
> symfony doctrine:build-sql
> symfony doctrine:drop-db
> symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```