# Symfony: Executing custom SQL in a task

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, connection, pdo, task

I basically want to create a custom doctrine task that truncates data in all the tables. I was trying this approach by getting the active Doctrine connection, and executing custom SQL statements that truncate the tables. After I finally got the connection, I got a fatal error stating `PDO::execute()` is an undefined method. Do I need to include a file?

Code:

```
$connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase('doctrine');
$st = $connection->execute("...............");
```

Thanks

Comment: I had another problem when writing my own task, all the SQL statements were being printed on the console. Found the solution here: http://www.martinsikora.com/symfony-silent-clear-cache
You need to pass NULL as the 1st param to the task (where you pass $this->dispatcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you were looking for [exec](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php).

Comment: OMG! Is it? Sorry, its been a while since I used PDO. Guess you are right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to the drop the DB each time:

```
> symfony doctrine:build-sql
> symfony doctrine:drop-db
> symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

Source: [How to make 'symfony doctrine:build-sql' task generate 'DROP' statments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626234/how-to-make-symfony-doctrinebuild-sql-task-generate-drop-statments)